Asynchronous API call in R
I have an R script that sends whatsapp messages using Meta's API... According to the documentation, it should be possible to send up to 80 messages per second, however it seems like batch messaging is not supported and you have to make an API call for each message you send
The API takes almost 1 second to respond, making sending thousands of messages impractical. I was wondering if it is possible to have a "fire and forget" approach in R, sending the API requests and not waiting for a response before sending the next API request
This is my last failed attempt to do so:
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(callr)

send_message <- function(number, variables, template, meta_number, meta_key, image_id = NA) {
    # Function to send the request, executed asynchronously
    send_request <- function(number, variables, template, meta_number, meta_key, image_id) {
        # Retrieve your environment variables
        meta_access_key_id <- meta_key
        whatsapp_number <- meta_number
        
        # Define the URL
        url <- paste0('https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/', whatsapp_number, '/messages')
        
        # Set up the headers
        headers <- c(
            'Content-Type' = 'application/json',
            'Authorization' = paste('Bearer', meta_access_key_id)
        )
        
        # Dynamically create parameters list based on variables vector
        parameters_list <- lapply(variables, function(var) {
            list(type = 'text', text = var)
        })
        
        # Initialize the components list
        components <- list()
        
        # If image_id is provided, add the image component
        if (!is.na(image_id) && image_id != "") {
            image_component <- list(
                type = 'header',
                parameters = list(
                    list(
                        type = 'image',
                        image = list(id = image_id)
                    )
                )
            )
            components <- c(components, list(image_component))
        }
        
        # Add the body component
        body_component <- list(
            type = 'body',
            parameters = parameters_list
        )
        components <- c(components, list(body_component))
        
        # Create the body of the request
        body <- list(
            messaging_product = 'whatsapp',
            recipient_type = 'individual',
            to = paste0('57', as.character(number)),
            type = 'template',
            template = list(
                name = template,
                language = list(code = 'es'),
                components = components
            )
        )
        
        # Convert the body list to JSON
        body_json <- toJSON(body, auto_unbox = TRUE)
        
        # Fire the request using httr
        POST(url, add_headers(.headers = headers), body = body_json, encode = 'json')
    }
    
    # Call the request function asynchronously using callr::r_bg()
    callr::r_bg(send_request, args = list(number, variables, template, meta_number, meta_key, image_id))
    
    # Return immediately without waiting
    return(invisible(TRUE))
}


callr::r_bg spawns a new R session each time it is called. Starting a R session takes some time ...

@Billy34 callr::r_bg makes the function run a lot faster than running send_request() by its own though... The problem is that the API call is not sent successfully when you run send_message(), but it is successful when you run send_request()
